# XML index makes query slower - any suggestions? (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a very unruly, ultra-large XML field and table. One XSD, but with a lot of variation within.

We tried adding the primary and secondaries (all independently) three indexes, and all we got was a MUCH bigger table, with queries that ran slightly slower.

It doesn't seem like we can easily type our XML, which I've read helps considerably.

Sample Query.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
where xml_info.value ('(//ABC/ABCFreeTx) [1]','varchar (80)') <> 'SUCCESSFUL'
```

Comment: Ben - that's exactly what I've asked.

Comment: 8 years later :) Ever find out anything?  I have a xml field (I've tried element based or attribute based) that is only a container with 30ish 'fields' (element or attribute).  Running a query with no indexes take around 10 seconds, and after I add Xml indexes, the query then takes ~40 seconds.  You can see my comment about something weird going on with the Xml index with too many rows read.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455933/sql-xml-query-slower-with-xml-indexes

Comment: There are several tricks you can do (make sure to get the first element, like“myxml.value(‘(/mynode)[1], ‘bigint’)”, but I never did get better performance with the xml indexes. :(

Comment: @Terry just reads the other post and yeah, you’ve gotten at least as far as I. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Although SQL Server provides some support to data structured as XML, it is **not** a recommended way of storing data -- its nature just don't fit well into RDBMs.

If you need to search on data imputed as XML, I'd suggest to create a trigger on insert/update to get the searchable data and store it in regular columns (so they can be properly indexed), and leave the XML data into a text field (i.e `VARCHAR(MAX)`).

Comment: Oh, absolutely.  But the data within one record winds up as 19 separate tables/sub-tables, and the queries to not just pull out useful data but to link it into a useful query is a beating.  So, we'll look at doing post parsing, denormalized quasi-parsing, sparse fields, etc - but what I'm primarily hoping for are different ways to query data such that the indexes will get used.  I'll double the size of the indexes (the SAN guys didn't need those terabytes anyhow) if it means the end-user/report-writers can use wind up with code that runs lots faster.