# SQL XML Query slower with XML Indexes

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT
p.pProfileXml.value(''(Profile/ssn)[1]'', ''int'') ssn, 
p.pProfileXml.value(''(Profile/date-birth)[1]'', ''date'') [date-birth],
p.pProfileXml.value(''(Profile/bad-field)[1]'', ''varchar(max)'') [bad-field],
p.pProfileXml.value(''(Profile/cb-bal)[1]'', ''float'') [e1_f1],
p.pProfileXml.value(''(Profile/date-hire-orig)[1]'', ''date'') [e1_f2],
p.pProfileXml.value(''(Profile/date-birth)[1]'', ''date'') [e2_f1]
FROM Profile p WHERE p.pgKey = 52
```

It takes about 20 seconds to run.  There are ~300K rows in Profile table, of which ~43K are associated with pgKey = 52.

I was hoping to get this query much more performant.  After adding Xml primary (and secondary) index(es), the execution time is now 30-40 seconds?!

Can anyone think/explain a reason why *reading* results from this table is now slower with XML Indexes on?

**UPDATE**

Some performance numbers:

```
-- Nonclustered pKey, no Xml Indexes - 10-11 secs
-- Clustered pKey, no Xml Indexes - 10 secs
-- Clustered pKey, Primary Xml Index - 37-41 secs
-- Clustered pKey, Primary Xml Index, secondary PROPERTY Index - 37-41 secs
```

Also, there seems to be an issue with my XML primary (secondary PROPERTY index).  When I hover over index in execution plan, the number of rows read is always WAY bigger than actual rows.  That seems wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why are all your strings wrapped in double single quotes (`''`)? That's going to cause an error.

Comment: try adding `/text()` to the end of each of your nodes paths (for example `Profile/ssn/text()`); that should improve performance due to the way that the values are extracted.

Comment: '' is because I copied the 'select' portion from a string sent via `sp_executesql` and forgot to clean it up.

Comment: @Larnu Adding /text() did help.  So now, without Xml indexes, my query finishes in 13 seconds.  Should I add Xml indexes back on and try to run or will it still not surpase the speed without Xml indexes?

Comment: Best method is to add, test, then remove, test. See which is more performant, but adding `text()` will improve it either way.

Comment: @Larnu Added some timing info along with a question about my index.